# How can I update a state inside an array of object with Redux?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, redux

My app has 2 tabs and I need to modify the content according the click in tab
I have this state:

```
const example = {
  tabs: [
    {
      id: 111,
      title: 'Python',
      icon: 'Python@2x.svg',
      content: 'Hello World'
    },
    {
      id: 333,
      title: 'EQL',
      icon: 'EQL@2x.svg',
      content: 'Hello World 2'
    }
  ]
}
```

and I need to change the 'content' inside of tabs. I tried this:

```
return {
    ...state,
    tabs: {
      ...state.tabs,
      content: 'Uhuuuul'
    }
}
```

But this didn't work! Could someone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map`:

```
return {
    ...state,
    tabs: state.tabs.map(tab => ({...tab, content: "Uhuuuul"}))
}
```

Comment: And how can I update only a specific tab?
I tried this, but it is wrong:
     ``` return {
        ...state,
        tabs: state.tabs.map(
          tab => {
            if(tab.id === action.id) {
              ({...tab, content: action.content}) 
            }
          }
        )
      }```

Comment: `return { ...state, tabs: state.tabs.map( tab => tab.id === action.id ? ({...tab, content: action.content}) : tab ) }`

Comment: yours not working because you're not returning anything. if the arrow function has `{}` block, you need to use return. but if it uses `({})`, it would return the object.

Comment: omg! i love you, guys! hahaha thanks so much, @Jack Bashford and kkesley